# Why reactive form Validator.email is not working for "this.form.invalid"

Tags: angular, angular6, mean-stack, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working with reactive forms and using form validators for validating fields. I have applied two validations on the email field.

```
loginForm = this.fb.group({
userEmail : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
userPassword : ['', Validators.required] 
});
```

this works when I apply single field validation and I can show error for both validation but when I use login time validation for whole form

```
this.loginForm.invalid
```

then it works for only validator.required but not for validator.email.

```
this.loginForm.invalid
```

returns false even if I don't add correct email type.

Comment: What did you enter? Do you have a reproducible example? I can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rug8dw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Now my example is working fine. Do you still want to know?

Comment: So you can't reproduce it either? Delete your question then.

Answer (score -1):

Add **Validators.compose** to your code and try:

```
loginForm = this.fb.group({
userEmail : ['',  Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
userPassword : ['', Validators.required] 
});
```

For more information and understanding about this, you can refer to [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/).

Comment: Working fine now.

Comment: No need for compose, its called internally when creating a form control